# How to get device type in Ripple emulator?

Tags: ripple

I implemented automatic theme applying feature using the [Navigator userAgent Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) to guess the device type. When running in the Ripple emulator this property returns my desktop browser's user-agent.

Does Ripple allow to determine the current device in other way?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using phonegap this link can help you to identify the device http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.name